# Relational Schema of a Specialization {Mandatory, OR} when child entities also contain primary keys

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have a parent table Venue (venueId[PK],venueName) and two child tables, Performance (performanceId[PK], performanceName) and Meal (mealId[PK], mealName) with a {Mandatory, OR} relationship. When mapping this to a relational schema the child tables are supposed to get the primary key of the parent table. What happens to the already existing primary keys in the child tables. How should this problem be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what way are those "child tables" if they don't have FKs to a "parent"? If you are giving tables, you already *have* a relational schema, because a relation schema is a description of tables and constraints.

Also, "parent" and "child" have no meaning without some notion of participation in a relationship/association type or FK between tables.

So it seems that you have three *entity types*, which would each get an *entity type table*, and you want one or more additional *relationship/association types* involving some of them. Namely "venue *venueId* hosts performance *performanceId*" and "*venueId* serves meal *mealId*". For those two relationship/association types, you would have PKs (respectively) {venueID, performanceId} and {venueId, meanlId} and the obvious participations/FKs for performanceId, venueId & mealId.

You might consider performances and/or meals to be *weak entities*, by that is a design aspect that you haven't addressed.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand the child tables already have the Primary key of the Parent table as foreign keys. In addition to that they already do have their own independent primary keys as well
So there would no be any issue or clash.